# How to parse simple pango-like markup using C++, getting a tree like structure of nodes?

Tags: c++, parsing, xml-parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, markup

I'm trying to parse Pango-style markup into a tree like structure with the leaves being the text elements and the branches the tag elements with the attributes. For example:

```xml
<b>This is bold</b>, <i>italic and <span color="red">red text</span></i> !
```

I've got below C++ code so far (without class definitions, they're irrelevant I think), which works fine if you leave out the `<b></b>` part above - it can only parse one tag per level, but it fails on multiple tags per level:

```cpp
        bool parseStartTag(const std::string& s, size_t start, size_t end, std::string& tag_name, std::map<std::string, std::string>& attrs) {
            size_t tag_name_end = s.find_first_of(" \t\n", start);
            if (tag_name_end == std::string::npos or tag_name_end >= end) {
                tag_name = s.substr(start, end - start);
                return true;
            } else {
                tag_name = s.substr(start, tag_name_end - start);
            }
            start = tag_name_end;

            char quote = '\0';
            std::string attr_name = "";
            std::string attr_value = "";
            while (start <= end) {
                if (quote != '\0') {
                    if (s[start] == quote) {
                        quote = '\0';
                        attrs[attr_name] = attr_value;
                        attr_name = "";
                        attr_value = "";
                    } else {
                        attr_value += s[start];
                    }
                } else if ((s[start] == ' ' or s[start] == '\t' or s[start] == '\n') and quote == '\0') {
                } else if (s[start] == '"' or s[start] == '\'') {
                    quote = s[start];
                } else if (s[start] != '=') {
                    attr_name += s[start];
                }
                start++;
            }

            return true;
        }

        std::shared_ptr<SGMarkupTag> parse(const std::string& s, std::string tag_name) {
            std::shared_ptr<SGMarkupTag> tag = std::make_shared<SGMarkupTag>();
            tag->setName(tag_name);
            
            size_t opening_index = 0;
            size_t closing_index = 0;
            size_t tag_content_start = 0;
            size_t tag_content_end = 0;
            while (closing_index != std::string::npos) {
                opening_index = s.find("<", closing_index);
                std::string text_string;
                if (opening_index != std::string::npos) {
                    text_string = s.substr(closing_index, opening_index - closing_index);
                } else {
                    text_string = s.substr(closing_index);
                }
                tag->addText(text_string);

                if (opening_index == std::string::npos) {
                    return tag;
                }

                closing_index = s.find(">", opening_index);
                if (opening_index != std::string::npos and closing_index == std::string::npos) {
                    SG_LOG(SG_GENERAL, SG_ALERT, "Markup parse error: Missing closing bracket for tag after opening bracket at char " << opening_index << ":");
                    SG_LOG(SG_GENERAL, SG_ALERT, "\t" << s);
                    SG_LOG(SG_GENERAL, SG_ALERT, "\t" << std::string(opening_index, '-') << "^");
                    return tag;
                }

                std::string tag_name = "";
                std::map<std::string, std::string> attrs;
                if (!parseStartTag(s, opening_index + 1, closing_index, tag_name, attrs)) {
                    return tag;
                };
                tag_content_start = closing_index + 1;

                opening_index = closing_index + s.substr(closing_index).rfind("</");
                if (opening_index == std::string::npos) {
                    SG_LOG(SG_GENERAL, SG_ALERT, "Markup parse error: Missing closing tag after opening tag at char  " << closing_index - 1 << ":");
                    SG_LOG(SG_GENERAL, SG_ALERT, "\t" << s);
                    SG_LOG(SG_GENERAL, SG_ALERT, "\t" << std::string(closing_index - 1, '-') << "^");
                    return tag;
                }
                tag_content_end = opening_index;
                closing_index = opening_index + s.substr(opening_index).rfind(">");
                if (closing_index == std::string::npos) {
                    SG_LOG(SG_GENERAL, SG_ALERT, "Markup parse error: Missing closing bracket for tag after opening bracket at char " << opening_index << ":");
                    SG_LOG(SG_GENERAL, SG_ALERT, "\t" << s);
                    SG_LOG(SG_GENERAL, SG_ALERT, "\t" << std::string(opening_index, '-') << "^");
                    return tag;
                }
                std::string closing_tag_name = s.substr(opening_index + 2, closing_index - opening_index - 2);
                if (closing_tag_name != tag_name) {
                    SG_LOG(SG_GENERAL, SG_ALERT, "Markup parse error: Unmatched closing tag '" << closing_tag_name << "' at char " << opening_index + 1 << " for opening tag '" << tag_name << "':");
                    SG_LOG(SG_GENERAL, SG_ALERT, "\t" << s);
                    SG_LOG(SG_GENERAL, SG_ALERT, "\t" << std::string(opening_index + 1, '-') << "^");
                    return tag;
                }

                std::shared_ptr<SGMarkupElement> sub_tag = parse(s.substr(tag_content_start, tag_content_end - tag_content_start), tag_name);
                sub_tag->setAttributes(attrs);
                sub_tag->setParent(tag);
                sub_tag->setRoot(tag->getRoot());
                tag->addChild(sub_tag);

                closing_index++;
            }
            tag->addText(s.substr(closing_index));

            return tag;
        }
```

Now, how could I change the while loop in `parse` to work for multiple tags per level ? I know this is no code writing service, but some pointers as to what I need to add or change, would be nice.

Comment: What's the relationship between SGMarkupElement and SGMarkupTag? Does SGMarkupTag inherit from SGMarkupElement ? ALso 
`sub_tag->setParent(tag); ...
tag->addChild(sub_tag);`
is likely a memory leak unless setParent is calling .get() on the shared pointer.

Comment: @jwezorek yes, SGMarkupElement is a common base of SGMarkupText and SGMarkupTag. As for the memory leak … I didn't observe one ? .get() is not called on the shared pointer

Comment: could also use a weak pointer from children to parents. The issue is you can't have shared pointers from parents to children and from children to parents because reference counting can't handle cycles.

Comment: @jwezorek okay, when I get any problems with it I know where to fix them  ! ;)

Answer (score 5):

To parse multiple elements on the same level you need to not assume that the closing tag associated with a particular opening tag will always be the last closing tag in the string (by closing tag I mean `</b>`, `</i>` etc.). In fact, the closing tag of a particular element may not even be the next closing tag after the opening tag because other elements could be nested inside of the element being parsed or even the next closing tag of the same type because another element of the same type may be nested in an element. There is no simple trick you can use to ignore arbitrarily recursive structure.

Basically you should refactor your code to be a [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

To do this you need a set of mutually recursive functions that return parsing output *and* the location in the input just to the right of what was consumed by the function. Each parsing function knows how to parse one kind of thing and is allowed to fail. By "allowed to fail", I mean that parsing failures should not throw exceptions or error out in cases in which the input is not definitely invalid. If cases where the input is not definitely invalid do not throw or otherwise panic then you can parse disjunctions (*or*-clauses) by trying to parse an *x* at the current location and seeing if the *x* parser succeeds; if not move on to the *y* parser...

You then need to be clear on what output you want exactly; that is, you need to be clear on the grammar you are parsing. In your example, it is unclear to me what `<b>This is bold</b>, <i>italic and <span color="red">red text</span></i>` even *should* return because I don't know where the comma between the bold element and the italic element would go. So say you disallowed that. Say you allow each element to contain either text or a sequence of other elements. Then to make a recursive descent parser for that grammar you could use parsing functions with signatures like the following:

```
std::shared_ptr<Tag> parseOpeningTag(const std::string& inp, int& i);
bool parseClosingTag(const std::string& inp, int& i, const std::string& tag);
std::shared_ptr<Element> parseElement(const std::string& inp, int& i);
std::string parseText(const std::string& inp, int& i);
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Element>> parseElementSequence(const std::string& inp, int& i);
```

Note that the `i` parameters in the above are references. If parsing succeeds `i` will end up containing the new location to start parsing from. If parsing fails, the return values will be null or false and `i` will be unchanged.

In such a set up the element parsing function would look like

```
std::shared_ptr<Element> parseElement(const std::string& inp, int& i) {
    auto tag = parseOpeningTag(inp, i);
    if (!tag) {
        return {};
    }
    auto element = std::make_shared<Element>(tag->name(), tag->attributes());

    // contents are either a sequence of elements or text; try elements first
    auto children = parseElementSequence(inp, i); 
    if (!children.empty()) {
        element->setChildren(children);
    } else {
        // We assume here that parseElementSequence does not change i if
        // it fails.
        auto txt = parseText(inp, i); 
        element->setText(txt);
    }
    bool success = parseClosingTag(inp, i, tag->name());
    if (!success) {
        throw std::runtime_error("bad element: " + tag->name());
    }
    return element;
}
```

And you would write `parseElementSequence` in terms of `parseElement`, calling it in a loop until it fails, etc.